# Checkbox wont uncheck in IE8

Tags: html, input, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

I've looked at a few similar problems and solutions but can't figure out what's going on here.

I have a single checkbox, and the problem basically is that in IE8 it cannot be unchecked. I had some jQuery attached to the click event initially to hide another part of the form, and it is also checked by default - I've now removed the jQ and the default checkstate, it's literally just a checkbox...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mailing" name="mailing" />
```

Clicking it once checks it, but clicking it again doesn't uncheck it.

The only other thing influencing it is some CSS, but that just floats it and sets the background colour.

Anyone know what on Earth is going on here?

(PS: If you want to try it it is available on the live site here: http://marldonchristmastrees.co.uk/choose-your-own-booking/

If you click through until the form appears, it is the "Join mailing list" checkbox at the bottom)

Comment: @idonteven No. This is not true.

Comment: Okay thanks for that tip...but i always do this. I´ll delete that wrong comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mailing" checked="checked" name="mailing" />
```

This should solve it. You need checked="**checked**", not checked="**true**".

Comment: That selects the box by default fine, but the issue is that once it's checked it cannot be unchecked - even using the JS console, with stuff like $("#mailing").attr("checked",""), it doesn't work.

Comment: You can un-check the checkbox in jQuery by doing `$('#mailing').removeAttr('checked');` - you have to _remove_ the attribute, not set its value to nothing